# Node getting empty array as result when post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am testing my post method on Postman.
Whenever I post the result it would display empty array [].
I console logged it on the node side and it returns empty array as well.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    password TEXT
)

INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);


app.post('/api/users', function(req, res, next) {
    db.post_user([req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password], function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
        else res.json(user);
    })
})
```

I am not exactly sure why I am getting empty array instead of actual data passing in.[image]

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cors = require('cors');
var massive = require('massive');
var config = require('./config');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var db = massive.connect({connectionString: config.connectionString},     function(err, localdb){
    db = localdb;
    app.set('db', db);

});

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res, next) {
    db.get_users(function(err, users) {
        if(err) res.status(500).json(err);
        else res.json(users);
    })
})
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res, next) {
    db.post_user([req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password], function(err, user) {
        console.log(req.body);
        if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
        else res.json(user);
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("I am listening");
})
```

Comment: Please show more node code.

Comment: Have you `console.log`'d `req.body` and ensured your post data is coming through?

Comment: From what I see, it has something to do with `db.post_user`. Can you show us what that is doing? Or it could be what @RobM. suggested. Make sure you are using `body-parser` if using `express`.

Comment: Put all the node code.
@GaryJohnson the post_user is the one that does  INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);

Comment: Console loggin req.body gives: { username: 'test5', email: 'test2', password: 'test2' }

Comment: Because you are not returning anything. Where is your `RETURNING *` part of the query? It's not even there, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to do something like:

```
let query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
let values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password]
connection.query(query, values).then(function(user...)
```

Depend of what Library are you using